# JSON Parser in Java for NYTimes API

Tags: java, json, api

I'm *very new to parsing JSON*, and I don't understand why I can't parse my JSON form, which I got from the NYTimes API. I thought I was following the hierarchy of "response" ---> "docs" ----> "web_url", but I'm getting an error. I want to be able to get all the "web_url" in the form.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import JSON.JSONException;
import JSON.JSONObject;


public class TestJSONParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, JSONException {
        String jsonData = "";
        BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String line;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Desktop/nytimes.txt"));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonData += line + "\n";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);

    System.out.println("nytimes:\n" + obj.getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("docs").getString("web_url"));

}
}
```

Here is what part of what the file looks like:

```
{
"response": {
    "meta": {
        "hits": 21,
        "time": 361,
        "offset": 0
    },
    "docs": [{
        "web_url": "http:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/reuters\/2014\/11\/01\/world\/europe\/01reuters-ireland-politics.html",
        "snippet": "Tens of thousands of people marched in towns across Ireland on Saturday in a second day of mass protests against water charges, the biggest display of opposition to government austerity measures since the country's banking crisis and bailout in 2010....",
        "lead_paragraph": "Tens of thousands of people marched in towns across Ireland on Saturday in a second day of mass protests against water charges, the biggest display of opposition to government austerity measures since the country's banking crisis and bailout in 2010. ",
        "abstract": null,
        "print_page": null,
        "blog": [],
        "source": "Reuters",
        "multimedia": [],
        "headline": {
            "main": "Mass Water Protests Put Pressure on Irish Government",
            "print_headline": "Mass Water Protests Put Pressure on Irish Government"
        },
        "keywords": [],
        "pub_date": "2014-11-01T13:21:35Z",
        "document_type": "article",
        "news_desk": "None",
        "section_name": "World",
        "subsection_name": "Europe",
        "byline": {
            "person": [],
            "original": "By REUTERS",
            "organization": "REUTERS"
        },
        "type_of_material": "News",
        "_id": "5455176038f0d84a08fb19f9",
        "word_count": "543"
    }, {
        "web_url": "http:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/aponline\/2014\/11\/01\/world\/europe\/ap-eu-ireland-water-protests.html",
        "snippet": "Organizers say at least 100,000 people are marching against Ireland's new tax on water, a charge imposed as part of the country's successful exit from an international bailout.",
        "lead_paragraph": "Organizers say at least 100,000 people are marching against Ireland's new tax on water, a charge imposed as part of the country's successful exit from an international bailout.",
        "abstract": null,
        "print_page": null,
        "blog": [],
        "source": "AP",
        "multimedia": [],
        "headline": {
            "main": "Marchers Protest Ireland's New Tax on Water Supply",
            "print_headline": "Marchers Protest Ireland's New Tax on Water Supply"
        },
        "keywords": [],
        "pub_date": "2014-11-01T10:58:03Z",
        "document_type": "article",
        "news_desk": "None",
        "section_name": "World",
        "subsection_name": "Europe",
        "byline": {
            "person": [],
            "original": "By THE ASSOCIATED PRESS",
            "organization": "THE ASSOCIATED PRESS"
        },
        "type_of_material": "News",
        "_id": "5454f5aa38f0d839202eac78",
        "word_count": "128"
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" JSON.JSONException: Missing value at 1 [character 2 line 1]
at JSON.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
at JSON.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:388)
at JSON.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:207)
at JSON.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:323)
at TestJSONParse.main(TestJSONParse.java:38)
```

Comment: Print out JSONData and make sure it looks OK.  Also, it may be that there's a Byte Order Mark at the start of the file that is getting garbled by your read sequence or that the parser doesn't understand how to process.

Comment: When I printed JSONData, I got this in front of the form, which might be what you described garbled by my read sequence: {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1265\cocoasubrtf210
{\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720

\f0\fs24 \cf0 \. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Is this the parser you're using? https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/ (From json.org?)

Comment: Nope, that's not a BOM (which is only 2-3 bytes), that's garbage.  There's something wrong with your download operation.

Comment: I second that your download operation isn't providing you with valid json. I was able to take your original input string (pre-edit) and parse it with the parser I linked in a previous comment.

Comment: I tried a new way where I take the form directly from calling the api, which gives me the right format. However, I'm now having a problem with parsing the "web_url". This is the part of my code that parses (I used the json.org parser you mentioned), and I don't understand why I'm getting the error of "JSONObject["docs"] not found". `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jstr);
  JSON.JSONArray arr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("docs");
  String blurb = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
 blurb += arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("web_url");}`